# Why doesn't std::noskipws work, or what is it supposed to do?

Tags: c++, std, cin

First off my understanding is that

```
cin >> std::noskipws >> str;
```

should stick a whole line from `cin` like "i have spaces" into `str`.  However this only puts "i" into `str`.  This could be a false assumption in which case what does `std::noskipws` do?

I know there is a function `std::getline` and that does work but simply for educational purposes I decided I would try to get `std::noskipws` to work for me.  I have tried in the past and it just never works so I normally move on and use `std::getline`.

What I think I have found so far is that `std::noskipws` technically just unsets `std::skipws` which internally to the `basic_iostream` just calls

```
ios_base::unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
```

or

```
ios_base::unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
```

So I tried inheriting my own stream form `basic_iostream` and setting those flags (unsetting) them manually.  Still no dice.

So, am I just totally off base or is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Good question; welcome to SO :)

Comment: Maybe you want to [change the delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304184/3484570), but I doubt it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

std::noskipws tells the istream to not skip any leading white space when attempting to read a type.  When there is no leading white space, then the flag has no impact.

Comment: ahh, fair enough,  i take it there is no flag to tell it that whitespace is not a delimiter?

Comment: @Digital: You can redefine whitespace however you like using the `std::ctype` formatting facet. If you are willing to wade into facets.

Comment: Or you can create a line class that has its own operator >> that reads a line.

Answer (score 3):

`std::skipws` works as follows: `std::istream` always keeps a current read position. If `std::skipws` is set, before `operator>>` is called the current read position is advanced to the first non-space character.

The behavior you're seeing (stop at the first space after `'i'`) is caused by `operator>>` for `std::string` (and `std::wstring`). That operator doesn't take the `std::istream` flags into account. An `operator<<` for another type may decide otherwise and continue even across spaces.