# changing the delimiter for cin (c++)

Tags: c++, stream, whitespace, delimiter, cin

I've redirected "cin" to read from a file stream `cin.rdbug(inF.rdbug())`
When I use the extraction operator it reads until it reaches a white space character.

Is it possible to use another delimiter? I went through the api in cplusplus.com, but didn't find anything.

Comment: You don't use `operator<<` with `std::cin`, did you mean `>>`?

Comment: you could try to [include white-space](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) characters in cin buffer.

Comment: @0x69 : That doesn't work. It just means that given the input "  A  B", extracting the first word gets you "  A" instead of "A".

Answer (score 53):

It is possible to change the inter-word delimiter for [`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) or any other [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream), using [`std::ios_base::imbue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/imbue) to add a custom [`ctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype) [`facet`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/facet).

If you are reading a file in the style of /etc/passwd, the following program will read each `:`-delimited word separately.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>


struct colon_is_space : std::ctype<char> {
  colon_is_space() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
  static mask const* get_table()
  {
    static mask rc[table_size];
    rc[':'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    return &rc[0];
  }
};

int main() {
  using std::string;
  using std::cin;
  using std::locale;

  cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new colon_is_space));

  string word;
  while(cin >> word) {
    std::cout << word << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `new` in uncontrolled way is evil, needless to say that you have not `delete` your struct (and there is no way to delete an unnamed pointer). ALWAYS try `shared_ptr` instead when possible.

Comment: That is generally excellent advice which does not apply in this specific case. In this case, `std::facet` is a refernce-counted pointer, `std::locale::locale` requires a raw pointer, not a shared pointer, and `std::locale::~locale` is defined to `delete` the facet pointer. If you have a problem with the interface to `locale`, take it up with the standards committee, not me. See the example program at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale

Comment: Even though I will suggest to define a wrapper function `get_locale` to wrap those unusual use of `new` with comments. So the code reviewer will realize there are something wrong with the interface, not the code writer. And this is what I mean for "controled" way of using `new`.

Comment: If not creating new functions, a better way to represent the ownership transfer could be `unique_ptr<colon_is_space>(new colon is_space).release()`. Although it is basically the same thing of your code but more verbose, it indicates that you are transferring pointer ownership.

Answer (score 25):

For strings, you can use the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) overloads to read using a different delimiter.

For number extraction, the delimiter isn't really "whitespace" to begin with, but any character invalid in a number.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can say the delimiter isn't "whitespace" for numbers, if `foo` is an `int`, `istringstream("123 456") >> foo;` puts `123` in `foo`, not `123456`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I didn't say that whitespace aren't delimiters, I said the set of delimiters is not only whitespace.  Try `istringstream("123_456") >> foo;` or Try `istringstream("123|456") >> foo;`

Comment: Ahhh, I understand, you're saying that rather than looking for a character defined as `ctype_base::space` the stream is looking for a character not defined as `ctype_base::digit`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Right, although it's more complex than that, some punctuation characters are allowed during numeric parsing.  And obviously whether it is classified as a space may affect the status flags, but whitespace is not the only thing that causes numeric extraction to stop.

Comment: Does it make sense to expect that `std::getline` is optimized for performance?

Comment: @Wolf streams in general are one of the least performant things in the standard. But typically you're going to use streams with input/output so slow performance will be negligible relative to the cost of the input/output operation. For performance reasons though arrays should be preferred over streams.

Comment: @JonathanMee: "slow performance will be negligible relative to the cost of the input/output operation" has NEVER been true in my experience.  The fact is that in many applications both file I/O and parsing are negligible compared to the cost of other processing, or waiting for the user to hit the start button, or network requests.  But in I/O heavy applications built with iostreams, it's the iostream code, not the I/O operations, that dominates.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess it's the type of project that I have a history with. Thanks for the clarification. It's good to have a balancing point of view. I suppose a better answer for @Wolf's question would be: "`getline` is no slower than the stream is as a whole, but if performance is a concern for you, you should look for non-stream options."

Answer (score 19):

This is an improvement on [Robᵩ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob%e1%b5%a9)'s answer, because that is the right one (and I'm disappointed that it hasn't been accepted.)

What you need to do is change the array that `ctype` looks at to decide what a delimiter is.

In the simplest case you could create your own:

```
const ctype<char>::mask foo[ctype<char>::table_size] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ctype_base::space};
```

On my machine `'\n'` is 10. I've set that element of the array to the delimiter value: `ctype_base::space`. A `ctype` initialized with `foo` would only delimit on `'\n'` not `' '` or `'\t'`.

Now this is a problem because the array passed into `ctype` defines more than just what a delimiter is, it also defines leters, numbers, symbols, and some other junk needed for streaming. ([Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt)'s answer touches on this.) So what we really want to do is *modify* a `mask`, not create one from scratch.

That can be accomplished like this:

```
const auto temp = ctype<char>::classic_table();
vector<ctype<char>::mask> bar(temp, temp + ctype<char>::table_size);

bar[' '] ^= ctype_base::space;
bar['\t'] &= ~(ctype_base::space | ctype_base::cntrl);
bar[':'] |= ctype_base::space;
```

A `ctype` initialized with `bar` would delimit on `'\n'` and `':'` but not `' '` or `'\t'`.

You go about setting up `cin`, or any other `istream`, to use your custom `ctype` like this:

```
cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new ctype<char>(data(bar))));
```

You can also switch between `ctype`s and the behavior will change mid-stream:

```
cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new ctype<char>(foo)));
```

If you need to go back to default behavior, just do this:

```
cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new ctype<char>));
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/qIBPWU)

Comment: that will set `bar['\t']` to zero, probably not intended.  To clear a bit, use `&~` (bit-wise AND with bit-wise NOT).  `!` is logical NOT and won't have the desired effect.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you, I wanted to strip out the `space` and `cntrl` bits and I accidentally got everything.

Answer (score 5):

This is an improvement on Jon's answer, and the example from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype_char). So this follows the same premise as both, but combines them with parameterized delimiters.

```
struct delimiter_ctype : std::ctype<char> {
    static const mask* make_table(std::string delims)
    {
        // make a copy of the "C" locale table
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        for(mask m : v){
            m &= ~space;
        }
        for(char d : delims){
            v[d] |= space;
        }
        return &v[0];
    }
    delimiter_ctype(std::string delims, ::size_t refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(delims), false, refs) {}
};
```

Cheers!