# I am very confused on how to parse multiple delimiters using getline and strtok in c++

Tags: c++, delimiter, text-parsing, string-parsing

My code is posted below. I want to be able to parse using the delimiters " ()," and convert the strings into integers in cpp.

```
while(getline(fin, line))
{
    x  = atoi((strtok(line.c_str(),'(,)'));
    xx = atoi((strtok(NULL,"(),"));
    xxx = atoi((strtok(NULL,"(),")));
    cout << x << "    " << xx << "    " << xxx << "\n";
}
```

but for some reason I get the following errors

GraphTest.cpp:134: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’

GraphTest.cpp:134: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘char* strtok(char*, const char*)’

The .c_str should convert my string into a c type string allowing me to use the atoi and strtok functions. I am very confused and would appreciate any help.

Comment: looks like you have a non-trivial grammar. pick a proper tool for lexing and parsing (e.g.: flex+bison or boost spirit, ...).

Comment: `'(,)'` is wrong. It should be `"(,)"`.

Comment: `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, it's supposed to be a constant not modifiable pointer to string internal buffer. `strotok()` **modifies** input string to perform tokenization (that's why it accepts `char*` instead of `const char*`) then simply it shouldn't be done like that.

Comment: This is a case of the X Y Problem; you're using the wrong tools for the job. Take a step back, and tell us what your input data looks like, and what the desired output is.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compile because `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, it's supposed to be a constant pointer to not modifiable internal `string` buffer. On the other hand `strtok()` accepts a `char*` because it modifies its input string.

Now you have two options: get a C string usable from `strtok()` or rewrite everything to be C++.

Create a new modifiable C string from your C++ string:

```
char* modifiableLine = strdup(line.c_str());

x  = atoi((strtok(modifiableLine, "(,)"));
// Other processing

free(modifiableLine);
```

You can do it if you have to keep a *big* amount of C code wrapped inside a C++ function/class. A better solution is to use what C++ Standard Library offers (also dropping `atoi()` C function if C++ 11). Let's first write an helper function:

```
int readNextInt(istringstream& is, const string& delimiters) {
    string token;

    if (getline(is, token, delimiters))
        return stoi(token);

    return 0; // End of stream?
}
```

Used like this:

```
istringstream is(line)
x = readNextInt(is, "(),");
xx = readNextInt(is, "(),");
xxx = readNextInt(is, "(),");
```

Please note that standard C++ function `getline()` doesn't accept a `string` for delimiters parameter but a single `char` only then you have to write your own overloaded version. Take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7304184/1207195) for good and nice possible implementation (you may also simply replace `getline()` with `is >> token` after `is.imbue()`, see given example).

Well...if you're already using Boost then you may simply use `boost::tokenizer`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with needing to parse with multiple delimiters and could not find a good solution anywhere so I ended up just making a function.

```
string getlineMultDelimiter(istream &is, string dlm, bool includeDelimiter)
{
    string str;
    char c;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && is)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < dlm.length() && !found; ++i)
            found = dlm[i] == is.peek();

        if (!found || includeDelimiter)
        {
            is.get(c);
            str += c;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

It will use all chars in the dlm string as a delimiter and you can choose whether to include the delimiter or not in the returned string.