# Using strtok to find substring

Tags: c++, strtok

I have a string of many letters

```
string path = "cxzaserds";
```

and a target word

```
string word = "cars";
```

In my function `match()`, I want to return true if the characters from `word` are found (in order) in path, in this case it would return true ('c' comes before 'a' comes before 'r' comes before 's' in the `path` string).

I'm trying to use `strtok()` to find each character one after another, with the delimiter being the current index's letter.

my progress:

```
bool match (string path, string word)
{
  char * cstr = new char [path.length()+1]; //workaround for strtok on string
  std::strcpy (cstr, path.c_str());

    char *p;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < path.length(); i++)
    {
    //error here, "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
      p = strtok (cstr, word[i]);

      if (p != NULL) //if strtok found word[i]
        continue;
      else return false; //was NULL, word not found
    }

  return true; //made it through, return true
}
```

On the C++ page, under delimiters, it says:

These can be different from one call to another.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

**What can I do to change the delimiter as strtok returns non-null?** Or another (easier) solution altogether?

Comment: 2nd parameter for `strtok` is `char*`, not `char` and `word[i]` is `char`. It's a **list of delimiters**, not single one. What I'd do? Drop `strotk` in favor of something more C++ish. [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27250298/1207195).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vlad mentioned, you shouldn't mix STL code (`std::string`) and classic c code (`strtok()`).

Instead you can use `std::string` members like `find()` or `find_first_of()` to solve your issue:

```
bool match(const std::string &path, const std::string &word) {
    std::size_t pos = 0; // position of the last match

    // iterate over all characters in 'word'
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        // look for the next character and store the new position
        if ((pos = path.find(word[i], pos)) == std::string::npos)
            return false; // return false if it couldn't be found
    }
    return true; // all characters have been found in order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this question so I do not want to repeat it entirely here. This question was asked here but I can not find it.
However you can see the answer at [my personal forum](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-1-40-00000017-000-0-0-1370451866)

Though the answer is written in Russian nevertheless the code is written in English.:) And moreover you can translate the description using web service translate.

As for using standard C function `strtok` with objects of type `std::string` then it is simply a bad idea and shall not be used.

The other approach is to use standard algorithm `std::all_of` along with standard C function `strchr`

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

```
p = strtok(cstr, word[i]);
```

As second parameter, you are passing `i`th character (type of which is `char`).

However, as the documentation states, second argument must be of type `const char *`, which means it's an array of delimiters. So you have a type mismatch.

The simplest solution would be to create an array of delimiters (note it's `NUL`-terminated, to it's actually a C-style string with one letter only):

```
char delimiters[] = { word[i], '\0' };
```

And then use it like this:

```
p = strtok(cstr, delimiters);
```

On the other hand, this approach is non-C++ style, and probably in real life you'd want to something else.

Comment: Why the downvote? Perhaps it's not the best solution, but it's valid and solves the issue described.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you're overcomplicating the target problem using a function that's not really made for this purpose (since it does a lot more).

Comment: I agree. Anyway, it's not off-topic, and it might be a good opportunity for @filposs to learn more on C types, as it seems he has some difficulties with this. Do we have a saboteur here? Other (even more correct) answers got downvoted too.

Answer (score 0):

`strchr` is much better than `strtok` for this problem; actually as others mentioned `strtok` is really badly designed and it's hard to think cases in which it's a good idea to use it.

`strchr` looks for the first occurrence of a character in a C string.

This problem using `strchr` becomes a one-liner even in C:

```
int match(const char *needle, const char *haystack) {
    while (haystack && *needle) {
        haystack = strchr(haystack, *needle++);
    }
    return haystack != NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your problem and the fact that C/C++ will allow you to address individual characters with plain subscripting then strtok would only seem to complicate the solution.

Something like (untested code!):

```
boolean hasWord ( char * needle, char * haystack) {
   int nlen = strlen(needle);
   int npos = 0;
   int hlen = strlen(haystack);
   int hpos = 0;
   for (hpos = 0 ; hpos < hlen ; hpos++) {
        if (needle[npos] == haystack[hpos]) {
            // got a match now look for next letter
            npos++;
            if (npos >= nlen) {
                // all letters now matched in sequence
                return true;
            }
        }
   }
   return false;
}
```