# How to copy a list of numbers from a string to a C++ vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, stringstream

I have a string like:

```
string line="6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1";
```

and I would like to copy the numbers within it to the respective elements of a std::vector. **I would like to use std::vector.assign() or std::copy().**

So I wrote:

```
string line="6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1";
vector<double> row;
istringstream iss { line };
row.assign(istream_iterator<double>(iss), istream_iterator<double>());
```

but the result is that assign() only copies the first number from the string to the vector, i.e. I get

```
row={6}
```

while I would like to get

```
row={6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1}
```

Same thing if I use std::copy instead, like in:

```
string line="6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1";
vector<double> row;
istringstream iss { line };
copy(istream_iterator<double>(iss), istream_iterator<double>(), back_inserter(row));
```

It looks like copy from the string ends after reading the first number, and I don't know why. Any idea how to use assign() or copy() to copy every number from the string into the vector?

Comment: `std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ');` before defining `iss`, like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/013c459db27390b5)

Comment: @PiotrS. Right on the spot. Now I'm wondering, is there a way to avoid the replacement? Something like defining the separtion character to `,`?

Comment: @AdriC.S. Yes! There is, however in your case I believe the replace is preferable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28197337/2642059

Comment: @AdriC.S. Yup, if setting up `istream`s to read in CSVs is something you have to do a lot, you could make a `const ctype<char>::mask` and just use that wherever. But if it's just this one place I'd side with `replace` cause lets be honest, using `ctype<char>::mask` is something no one does so it will make your code difficult to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get your `string` right you *can* do this all in one line with Visual Studio 2013:

```
string line="6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1";

std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ');

vector<double> row{istream_iterator<double>(istringstream(line)), istream_iterator<double>()};
```

Note that gcc has a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54316) with moving an `istream` so you'll have to do this on gcc:

```
string line="6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1";

std::replace(line.begin(), line.end(), ',', ' ');

istringstream bar(line);

vector<double> foo{istream_iterator<double>(bar), istream_iterator<double>()};
```

Thankfully the bug is already fixed in gcc 5, so we're almost there.