# C++ Do-While loop not accepting input multiple times

Tags: c++

I am a novice C++ programmer, and I'm having some trouble with this program. I want to input points, Cartesian plane style, but this code is acting like it doesn't see the `cin` any time but the first. `A` is a class that holds the points. When run, the program I am able to input one pair, but when it gets to the while loop, it says `Enter pair (0,0 to finish) Enter pair (0,0 to finish)...` repeatedly.

```
do {
    cout << "Enter pair (0,0 to finish) ";
    cin >> x >> y;
    A.add( x, y );
} while ( !(x==0 && y==0) );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter the two numbers with a space between them. The `std::in` does not know how to handle other types of separators (besides white spaces).

Comment: However, It is possible to [change the separator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304184/1925996).