# cannot set a std::string equal to the zeroth index of another std::string

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, std, ifstream

I'm attempting to read a text file character by character. I'm using a string to read the file. My code for reading the file is below:

```
int main()
{   
    std::ifstream data;
    data.open("C:\\Users\\Christian Dean\\Documents\\CodeLiteWorkspace\\CplusplusPractice\\src\\test_file.qz");
    std::string data_str;
    int counter = 0;
    data >> data_str;
    for(int i = 0; i < data_str.length(); i++)
    {
        std::string tokenizer = data_str[i];
        if (tokenizer == "output")
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    data.close();
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see, in my for loop I'm setting the string `tokenizer` equal to the zeroth index of the string `data_str`. However when compiling, it show the error

> `main.cpp:27:37: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to ''const char*' [-fpermissive].

I really don't know how else I can read the file character by character. I tried setting `tokenizer` as type `char`. But when I run the program it says the `counter` variable equals `0`. So obviously making the `tokenizer` variable a type `char` did not work.

The content of the text file is below if it is needed:

```
 output: "Hello World
```

Comment: Please describe what you want to do, as I do not see how reading character by character ever results in the string `output` in `tokenizer`, if `tokenizer` only contains one character at a time.

Comment: To expand on Yakk's comment, by walking the input one character at a time, you can never see a whole word. If instead you extracted strings until `data.eof ()` returned true, you would walk each word in the file, which you could compare and count against

Comment: Not sure if I'm misreading what nate intended with his comment, but fear the loop to eof. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: I was not aware of that pitfall, but the basic idea is the same with additional error checking.

Comment: Something tells me you could get some tokenizing ideas [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c) and its host of answers in varying degrees. There are *many* ways to tokenize input in C++. It's worth at least a few minutes of reviewing.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actual no. I was trying to see if I could tokenize a file, for practice. I appreciate the link though.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a "here's a canned solution" link. More for *ideas*. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh I know. I was just saying where I got my idea from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string data_str;
```

defines a `std::string`.

```
std::string tokenizer = data_str[i]
```

defines a `std::string` and attempts to construct the `string` with a single character. `std::string` has no constructor that accepts a single character.

Seeing as you're going to compare this single character string against a whole word, this isn't what you want to do anyway.

```
data >> data_str;
```

reads in whitespace delimited token--effectively one word plus any punctuation.

so

```
while (data >> data_str)
{
    stripPunctuation(data_str);
    if (data_str == "output")
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

`stripPunctuation` would look like `void stripPunctuation(std::string & input)` and would remove all punctuation, but I only included that hack as a simplified example. This approach would work, but a better solution is something like [changing the delimiter for cin (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c) to add all the punctuation you want to strip and let `>>` do the job for you.

Then you get

```
// configure stream to treat punctuation as whitespace here
while (data >> data_str)
{
    if (data_str == "output")
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

and you're done.

Comment: That is not operator =.  `std::string foo = blah;` does not involve `operator=` anywhere.

Comment: Gah. That will be a construct. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
std::string tokenizer = std::string(1, data_str[i]);
```

`std::string` doesn't have a constructor that takes a single `char`. However, the constructor overload which we are using takes a `char` in the second argument, and creates an `std::string` containing a repetition of that `char` of length given by the first argument.

Comment: demonstrates why this won't compile but makes no attempt to guide OP to a usable solution.