# How to read a dat file one line at a time and put the whole line into a variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a dat file using `c++` that has different data types on each line. Address, description, square footage, bedrooms, bathrooms.

Here is the dat file:

```
123 N Main Avenue, Albiny, NY 12206
This is the first house description.
1200
3
1.1
456 S Lake Street, Los Angeles, CA 90057
This is the second house description
1000
4
2.0
```

This is the code I have:

```
char address[255]     = { '\0' };
char description[255] = { '\0' };
int sqft              = 0;
int bedrooms          = 0;
float bathrooms       = 0.0;

ifstream dataFile;
dataFile.open(fileName);

while (dataFile >> address >> description >> sqft >> bedrooms >> bathrooms)
{
    House.setAddress(address);
    House.setDescription(description);
    House.setSqft(sqft);
    House.setBedrooms(bedrooms);
    House.setBathrooms(bathrooms);
    cout << "Debug tool: check to see if it made it in this while loop." << endl;
}
```

It is not reading the file. My guess is that it is attempting to put 123 (the house number of the first address) into `address` and it is not working because 123 is an int and not a string. How do I have each line get put into a variable so I can complete this operation?

Comment: You have to set your separator to `\n`.

Comment: @EliSadoff What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c) explains the procedure well.