# Extraction for second word. Parsing strings (C++)

Tags: c++, string, parsing, iostream, cout

I am trying to get rid of the comma and store the second word in `secondWord`, and then output `secondWord`.

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    istringstream inSS;       
    string lineString;        
    string firstWord;         
    string secondWord;       
    int i;
    bool correct = false;

    cout << "Enter input string:" << endl;

    while (!correct) 
    {
        // Entire line into lineString
        getline(cin, lineString);

        // Copies to inSS's string buffer
        inSS.clear();
        inSS.str(lineString);

        // Now process the line
        inSS >> firstWord;

        // Output parsed values
        if (firstWord == "q")
        {
            cout << "q" << endl;
            correct = true;
        }

        inSS >> secondWord;
        if(secondWord[i] != ',')
        {
            cout<<"Error: No comma in string."<<endl;
        }

        else if (secondWord[i] == ',')
        {

            cout << "First word: " << firstWord << endl;
            cout << "Second word: " << secondWord << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

acceptable inputs: 
Jill, Allen
Jill , Allen
Jill,Allen

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyZtP.png)

The code produces the comma as the second word, but I would like to get rid of the comma and space and out the second word.

Comment: seems like i is uninitialized

Comment: Anyway, you can look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c to learn about how to tokenize a string.

Comment: If i is uninitialized, the code behavior will be undefined so anything could happen. Anyway, you should provide us with a sample input, `a, b`, `a , b`, `a,b` could produce very different results using your code.

Comment: The problem is when you `inSS >> firstWord;` when your input is `Jill, Allen`, you take in the comma as well, so comma should never appear in your secondWord, thus the error. Go to the link I post earlier to learn how to tokenize string.

Comment: I read tokenize, but we have not learned that in class yet, and have to stick to the covered material.

Comment: You could change the whitespace delimiter to include comma.  Then it will extract words without the comma.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c

Comment: You can implement a tokenizer based on what you have learnt, by using string.find_first_of and string.find_first_not_of

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<string> tokenize(const string& line, const string& delimiters)
{
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    vector<string> result;
    while (end != string::npos)
    {
        start = line.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end);
        end = line.find_first_of(delimiters, start);
        if (start != string::npos && end != string::npos)
            result.push_back(line.substr(start, end - start));
        else if (start != string::npos)
            result.push_back(line.substr(start));
        else
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method returns the tokens separated by delimiters. If your delimiters is `", "`, then you need additional check to ensure that there is comma in between. If your delimiters is `","`, you will want to do some trimming of white spaces at the beginning and end of each word.