# Read file from .txt file in c++

Tags: c++, readfile

The contents of menu.txt are:

```
1 Fish Dish:Fish and chips
```

And my code is:

```
int itemNo;
string category;
string descript;

ifstream infile("menu.txt"); 
infile >> itemNo >> category >> descript;
cout << category  << " - " << descript << " - " << itemNo <<'\n';
```

I want to get:

```
Fish Dish - Fish and chips - 1
```

But for some reason I just get:

```
Fish - Dish:Fish - 1
```

Comment: `ifstream` uses whitespace as a delimiter by default, "Fish Dish" for example has a space in it.

Comment: How is `>> category` supposed know to read until `:`?

Comment: To change the delimiter, see [this questioin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the delimiter to be the colon. See [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c)

Or the simpler approach would be to use the `getline()` function:

`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim)`

So, for your example:

```
int itemNo;
string category;
string descript;

ifstream infile("menu.txt");
infile >> itemNo;
getline(infile, category, ':');
getline(infile, descript);
cout << category  << " - " << descript << " - " << itemNo <<'\n';
```

That will give:

```
 Fish Dish - Fish and chips - 1
```

To get rid of the extra space at the start of Fish Dish, add an extra getline.

```
int itemNo;
string category;
string descript;

ifstream infile("menu.txt");
infile >> itemNo;
getline(infile, category, ' ');
getline(infile, category, ':');
getline(infile, descript);
cout << category  << " - " << descript << " - " << itemNo <<'\n';
```