# How to use ',' as getline delimiter in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, getline

Here is my code. When I use '\t'  as delimiter with a dataset separated by \t it works, but when I use ',' with a dataset separated by ',' it does't works.

```
void TApp::LoadTree(char * fileName){
   ifstream in(fileName);
   char starID[200];
   double dRa,dDec,dU,dG,dR,dI,dZ;
   long w = 0;
   TStar * star;

   if (SlimTree!=NULL){

      if (in.is_open()){
         cout << "\nLoading objects ";
         while(in.getline(starID, 200, ',')){
            in >> dRa;
            in >> dDec;
            in >> dU;
            in >> dG;
            in >> dR;
            in >> dI;
            in >> dZ;
            in.ignore();
            star = new TStar(starID, dRa, dDec, dU, dG, dR, dI, dZ);
            SlimTree->Add(star);
            delete star;
            w++;
            if (w % 10 == 0){
               cout << '.';
            }//end if*/
         }//end while
```

The data file I am trying to read looks like this:

> 1237645876878180399,15.2062613727499,-1.02188584631684,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I recommend you stop using the stream `getline` member function, and instead use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) together with [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Check the stream status after reading to make sure you *are* reading.

Comment: 1237645876878180399,15.2062613727499,-1.02188584631684,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999 is not going to work how you are reading. There are many duplicates for reading csv files.

Comment: Unrelated: `star = new TStar(...);
            SlimTree->Add(star);
            delete star;` is unusual. If `Add(star)` stores the pointer, `delete star;` will invalidate the stored pointer. If `Add(star)` stores a copy of the pointed-at data you can `TStar star (...);
            SlimTree->Add(&star);` and save yourself from dynamically allocating. Plus the compiler may find some additional room for optimizing, especially if you change `Add` to accept a reference rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that you have a [comma-separated values (i.e. a CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, where the comma separates *all* fields.

Then your code won't work because the input operator `>>` don't know anything about any other separator than white-space.

It works with tabs (or other white-space) as separator because the `>>` operator *skips* leading white-space, and stops reading at white-space as well.

---

For CSV files I usually recommend that you find a library to help you read and parse them, because CSV files a *deceptively* simple, but in reality can contain many special and corner cases that makes reading them non-trivial.

If you still want to attempt to parse them yourself, then I really recommend that you first of all read *full lines* and attempt to parse each line separately. Then you have to remember to read the separator between *every* field.

Comment: You can change the delimiter if you really, really want to (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c)  but I second your recommendations.

Comment: ***the dataset is on a .txt file*** It does not matter what the extension is. It's still a CSV file.