# How does the input operator (>>) know where to stop and take the next input if the inputs are seperated by single spaces?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter two numbers:" << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The sum of " << v1 << " and " << v2 << " is " << v1 + v2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If the input given is `5 6`, it'll print "The sum of 5 and 6  is 11". But how does the `istream` know when to stop?

Does it keeps on taking input if its an integer and stops if it gets another data type?

How does it assign the correct values of `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: The default delimiter for std::cin is whitespace i.e. your blank. Check this out for additional info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302996/changing-the-delimiter-for-cin-c

Comment: OK, Thanks for answering

Comment: It stops when it reaches the first whitespace after the numbers, that whitespace remains on the stream for future read operations

Comment: @M.M I didn't get what happens to the whitespace. Does it get flushed?

Comment: @DeepakPawade No, it stays there

Answer (score 4):

(>>) is an extraction operator. It can be used more than once to accept multiple inputs. It differentiates the multiple inputs through spaces or the next line. In your case, there is a space between 5 and 6 so the extraction operator will assign 5 for v1 and 6 for v2.

Comment: yes, The default delimiter for std::cin is whitespace. Thanks for answering though!